# Knots in splines method, ns and rcs in R

Tags: r, regression, splines

Actually I want to use "ns" method but since I have a problem ([Error in visualize splines logistic regression with ns](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606025/error-in-visualize-splines-logistic-regression-with-ns)) to visualize log odds with "ns" method I forced to use "rcs" method.
I understand how "ns" is working but I am confused by knots and coefficients in "rcs" method.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please state a question?  What specifically is your problem and what is it you want to know?

Comment: I do not know how rcs works about number of knots and coefficients and placement of each knot.

Comment: And in other hand if I solve this problem (the link) I will able to use "ns" without thinking about "rcs" method. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/606025/error-in-visualize-splines-logistic-regression-with-ns

Comment: In that case, please edit your previous post rather than producing a new thread about the same problem.